# Performance measure Mysql View VS UNION of table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I try to make a database scheme. I just eager to know which methodology is better than other.
I have 2 ways to accomplish a searching task from my database.
   The condition as follows:
I have multiple table name as **table1,table2..tablen** with same structure which denote diffrent location.

My working way as follows:

1. Making a **VIEW** using **UNION** of my **TABLES** and use query like:
   `Select * from my_view where my_condition;`".
2. By using simple **UNION** operator and use query like:

   `select * from table1 where my_condition
   UNION
   select * from table2 where my_condition
   UNION
   ...
   ..
   select * from tablen where my_condition`

So my problem is that I want a faster solution sol please help me to choose between VIEW and UNION.If you have any other solution like mysql cluster **SCALABLITY** tell me.

Comment: If you have more than one table with the same structure, then you have a design problem... create one table, and add a location column to that one table - then the use of UNION becomes redundant

Comment: @MarkBaker we already discuss on this topic on my earlier post.
But I have a problem of lots of data I'm afraid of response speed.
I want a fats response database scheme.

Comment: Yes, we already discussed it; and you chose to ignore my advice to use a single table then. You'll get a faster more responsive database if you don't split across multiple tables, UNION will be a big overhead as you have to do n individual selects (where n is the number of tables you're unioning) and then join the results from each... while MySQL can reduce this overhead slightly for you with techniques like parallelisation, it will never be even close to the speed of accessing a single table

Comment: You have a fixation that millions of records is "big data" and will give you performance problems. It isn't big data! And a single table won't give performance problems if properly organised and indexed.... I recommended sharding if you felt you needed to do something (even though it's probably overkill for your small data volumes), you've ignored that advice... yet you choose to take an approach that will have serious performance repurcussions, and be far more problematic to manage and administer

Comment: @MarkBaker I like your advise of Sharding but as I'm a fresher so I didn't understand well how sharding and parallelisation work.Can you tell me how can I properly indexed my data in single table.

Comment: Sharding is basically a way of letting the database itself split the records in a single table across multiple blocks.... if you're working in a clustered or multiple server environment, then different blocks can be accessed from different servers, and each server can search some of those blocks in parallel, so each does a small amount of the search work, and then all the individual results are pulled together by the database itself to return to the requesting application. It's transparent to the application... from your perspective it still looks like a single large table.

Comment: Called partitioning in the MySQL docs - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html

Answer (score 0):

**View** is just a `saved Named SELECT statement` . when you call a view it just simply executes the SELECT statement in its definition there is no such performance benefits from view, but there are some security and code simplicity benefits. Unless you create `Indexed View` which can improve performance of your view as well as other queries which can benefit from the indexes created on your views. **Warning** Indexed views come with a long list of limitations.    
**Union Operator** vertically combines result sets from two or more select queries. If you want better performance you need to look at the indexes available on your table for your query.  
Carefully inspecting you query's Exection plan will be the best place to start in your case as it will give you some idea what steps SQL SERVER has to go through in order to get the required result set.

Comment: Can You give me idea how [olx](http://www.olx.com) or any other classified website database work.

Comment: sorry pal never heard of these websites.

Comment: No problem do you have ever used any classified website or yellopages.I want database schema like these website.